# Custom props validate in typescript

Tags: typescript

In Typescript world, I'm wondering how to add proper typing to `createView` function, so it validate arguments based on arguments of passed function?

```
type ViewFn = (...args: any) => any;
function createView(view: ViewFn, data: Object) : any {
    // how to validate data parameter
    return true;
}

// test cases

function ViewA(data: { input: string }) {
    return function() { return 'view A'; }
}
function ViewB(data: { input: boolean }) {
    return function() { return 'view B'; }
}

createView(ViewA, { input: 'some' }); // ok
createView(ViewA, { validate_me: 'some' }); // expect error

createView(ViewB, { input: true }); // ok
createView(ViewB, { input: 'some' }); // expect error
createView(ViewB, { validate_me: 'some' }); // expect error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the provided code snippet, you are not referencing the argument. The argument needs to be named, for example, as `T`. Then, the type of the `data` can be `T`, and the type of `view` can be `ViewFn<T>`.

From there, TypeScript will handle the rest, as it can infer the connection between the `data` argument of the function received in the `view` parameter and the `data` object of the `createView` function.

```js
type ViewFn<T> = (data?: T) => () => string;
```

```js
function createView<T>(view: ViewFn<T>, data?: T): boolean {
  return true;
}
```

In this example, we declared a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `T` in the `createView` function, and then stated that the attribute of the function received in the `view` argument matches this `T` type. Similarly, the `data` argument also matches the `T` type. Therefore, the `data` argument of the `ViewA` function received in `view` exactly corresponds to the `data` passed to the `createView` function.

Here's the updated code with the changes:

```js
type ViewFn<T> = (data?: T) => () => string; // Declare viewFn (A and B) type of arguments and return

// Declare view: as viewFn, data as argument of view
function createView<T>(view: ViewFn<T>, data?: T): boolean {
  return true;
}

function ViewA(data: { input: string }) {
  return function () {
    return 'view A';
  };
}
function ViewB(data: { input: boolean }) {
  return function () {
    return 'view B';
  };
}

// Test Cases
createView(ViewA, { input: 'something' }); // OK
createView(ViewA, { validate_me: 'something' }); // Error: Argument of type '{ validate_me: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ input?: string | undefined; }'.

createView(ViewB, { input: true }); // OK
createView(ViewB, { input: 'something' }); // Error: Argument of type '{ input: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ input?: boolean | undefined; }'.
createView(ViewB, { validate_me: 'something' }); // Error: Argument of type '{ validate_me: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ input?: boolean | undefined; }'.

createView((data: { input: 'something' }) => () => 'view C', { input: 'something' }); // OK

// Updated Test Cases (not working this solution, just with updated)
// New Test Cases
createView(() => () => 'view C', { input: 'something' }); // OK, but need - Error: Argument of type '{ input: 'something'; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ input: undefined; }'.
```

#### UPDATED (need use [`extends conditional type`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types))

The code outlined so far works perfectly when the `view` attribute of `createView()` is of object type and not undefined or null. So, when checking the `data` attribute of `createView()`, we need to ensure that the object is present. We can accomplish this by adding an [`extends`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) condition.

```js
type ViewFnData<T, D> = { [key in keyof D]: key extends keyof T ? T[key] : undefined }
```

Declare `data` as `D` of `createView(view, data)` as similar object than `data` as `T` of `view(data)`. If `D` has attribute what not declared in `T` then set type to `undefined`, else if exists this key then get original type from `T`.

```js
type ViewFn<T> = (data: T) => () => string; // Declare viewFn (A and B) type of arguments and return
type ViewFnData<T, D> = { [key in keyof D]: key extends keyof T ? T[key] : undefined } // Declare the type of the data object in the createView function, ensuring that the key-value pairs only include keys that exist in the T type and the values are either the corresponding values from T or undefined if the key is not present in the T type

// Declare T and D generic types (two unique types)
// where first given argument type is T and second given argument is D
// use T and D arguments to define really types what we enabled
// - view: viewFn<T>
// - data: viewFnData<T, D>
function createView<T, D>(view: ViewFn<T>, data?: ViewFnData<T, D>): boolean {
  return true;
}

// New Test Cases
createView(() => () => 'view C', { input: 'something' }); // Error: Argument of type '{ input: 'something'; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ input: undefined; }'.
createView(() => () => 'view C'); // OK (if createView()'s data is just optional)
```

```js
type ViewFn<T> = (data: T) => () => string; // Declare viewFn (A and B) type of arguments and return
type ViewFnData<T, D> = { [key in keyof D]: key extends keyof T ? T[key] : undefined } // Declare the type of the data object in the createView function, ensuring that the key-value pairs only include keys that exist in the T type and the values are either the corresponding values from T or undefined if the key is not present in the T type

// Declare view: as viewFn, data as argument of view
function createView<T, D>(view: ViewFn<T>, data?: ViewFnData<T, D>): boolean {
  return true;
}

function ViewA(data: { input: string }) {
  return function () {
    return 'view A';
  };
}
function ViewB(data: { input: boolean }) {
  return function () {
    return 'view B';
  };
}

// Test Cases
createView(ViewA, { input: 'something' }); // OK
createView(ViewA, { validate_me: 'something' }); // Error: Argument of type '{ validate_me: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ input?: string | undefined; }'.

createView(ViewB, { input: true }); // OK
createView(ViewB, { input: 'something' }); // Error: Argument of type '{ input: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ input?: boolean | undefined; }'.
createView(ViewB, { validate_me: 'something' }); // Error: Argument of type '{ validate_me: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ input?: boolean | undefined; }'.

createView((data: { input: 'something' }) => () => 'view C', { input: 'something' }); // OK
createView(() => () => 'view C', { input: 'something' }); // Error: Argument of type '{ input: 'something'; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ input: undefined; }'.
createView(() => () => 'view C'); // OK (if createView()'s data is just optional)
```

Comment: upvoting as this is close as well. Just one trick - if I want to make input as a required (as initially were in example) - it won't allow me to do that, even if I remove questionmarks from everywhere

Comment: It allows, I just provided a default value. I will remove it. However, I specifically check the 'data' argument of the viewA() and viewB() functions, while @nico's answer gives positive true results if other arguments are assigned outside of 'data'.

Comment: hmm, I'm getting an error `Argument of type '(data: { input: string; }) => () => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ViewFn<{ input: string; }>'.
  Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
    Type '{ input: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ input: string; }'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ input: string; }'.(2345)`

Comment: Could you share your test case with me? ---- In the meantime, I updated my solution and realized that I omitted the logic for cases where the function provided in the view has no arguments at all. The original code doesn't throw an error, but the updated code indicates that something is not right when the view function has no arguments, but the data is an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using Typescript [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

```js
type ViewFn<TArgs> = (...args: TArgs[]) => any;

function createView<TArgs>(view: ViewFn<TArgs>, data: TArgs): any {
  // how to validate data parameter
  return true;
}

// test cases

function ViewA(data: { input: string }) {
  return function () {
    return "view A";
  };
}
function ViewB(data: { input: boolean, validate_me: string }) {
  return function () {
    return "view B";
  };
}

createView(ViewA, { input: "some" }); // ok
createView(ViewA, { validate_me: "some" }); // expect error

createView(ViewB, { input: true, validate_me: "" }); // ok
createView(ViewB, { input: "some" }); // expect error
createView(ViewB, { validate_me: "some" }); // expect error
```

The Generic `TArgs` is automatically infered so you don't need to provide it to the createView function.

Comment: If `function ViewC(data: { notInput: string }, dataSecond: { input: string }) ...` then `createView(ViewC, { input: "some" });` will take fake positive true result. The question wants to check the 'data' argument, but in TypeScript, it will say it's fine because @nico's solution considers 'dataSecond' as a correct result... incorrectly. The perfect solution remains: `type ViewFn<T> = (data?: T) => () => string;`